# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Yes' to data type bit

Tags: sql

I used a case to change boolean column values to a text string that actually means something. Firstly, when doing a `WHERE` statement on these columns do I use the boolean values or the updated text strings?

I used:

```
WHERE TrainingProgram.blnInCatalogue = 'Yes' 
  AND TrainingProgram.blnActive = 'Inactive'
```

But I get the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Yes' to data type bit.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For true, try using:

```
WHERE TrainingProgram.blnInCatalogue <> 0
```

For false, try using:

```
WHERE TrainingProgram.blnInCatalogue = 0
```

The `blnInCatalogue` column is a bit field, and it doesn't understand what the string 'Yes' means.  It only knows 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can use a case to *display* bit columns as readable strings, their internal value is still `bit`. They can only be *compared* to `0` or `1`.